# import .xls files to mysql in java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, import-from-excel

I have a folder of 300+ xls files. The structure of this files is the same, but data is different. So I need to import this data to mysql table using servlets.
I think there are few stages:

1. Load a folder with files to server
2. Convert files to .csv
3. Import files one by one to mysql

But how can I implement this mechanism technically using servlets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First convert Xls to csv using this:

```
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/14301
```

Then Import the csv using this:

```
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t53674.html
```

Answer (score 0):

using apache poi you can easily read any number of xls file.
link :http://poi.apache.org/
 To insert it into database  it is not required to convert it into .csv. You can read each cell of each file .Since each file's structure is same a List of DTO formed by storing all value of you excel sheet can be directly inserted into database.
    You can get started at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

```
                    Best of Luck
```